# Symfony service declaration namespace

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection

I have strange problem with symfony2.
In service.yml I declared pagination service:

```
site.paginate_service:
class: "Smestaj\SiteBundle\Services\PaginationService"
arguments:
  - "@service_container"
```

Service looks like this:

```
namespace Smestaj\SiteBundle\Services;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
class PaginationService{

protected $cn;
protected $numberOfData;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->cn = $container;
    $this->numberOfData = $container->getParameter("limit")['adsPerPage'];
}
```

Problem is when I call this service in service.yml into another service as dependacy injection

```
site.ads_service:
class: "Smestaj\SiteBundle\Services\AdsService"
arguments:
  - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
  - "@service_container"
calls:
  - [setPaginate, ["@site.paginate_service"]]
```

then I get this error message:

> Attempted to load class "Services aginationService" from namespace "Smestaj\SiteBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

So, from this message it's clearly that symfony trying to call class "ServicesaginationService". My class has Smestaj\SiteBundle\Services\PaginationService.
Symfony, somehow merge Services and PaginationService name, and remove "P" from name.

If I Change Class name to AaaService then everything works fine.

Comment: Try to remove quotes from `class` values.

Comment: Its a bad idea to inject service_container to service itself. You should inject only dependant services, parameters, etc., but NOT service container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use double-quotes in class name in `service.yml`, you have to escape the `\` by adding another `\`:

```
class: "Smestaj\\SiteBundle\\Services\\PaginationService"
```

But the best way to avoid problems is to remove quotes, as the path will be corectly interpreted as string by the YML parser:

```
class: Smestaj\SiteBundle\Services\PaginationService
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your answer solved my problem